# Lost connection to iPhoneでアプリが落ちてしまいます。

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

アプリを実機で動作させると落ちてしまうときがあります。

その際、デバッグエリアに Received memory warning と複数回表示された後、以下の画像が出てきてアプリが落ちます。
ちょっと前まではこの現象は起こらず、最近になって急に出てきました。この際コードはいじっておらず、Storyboardのみいじりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

iOSシュミレータで実行させた場合は Received memory warning も表示されず、アプリも落ちません。

アプリを素早く動作させた時にも同様に落ちてしまうので、メモリを使いすぎてしまっているためのような気もするのですが、以前には出ていなかったので困惑しています。

どなたか何か知っている方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メモリ不足によりアプリがクラッシュしているだけかなと思われます。

一度XcodeのProfile機能を使って、実機で実行した際にどの程度メモリがアロケートされているのか計測してみてはいかがでしょうか。

なお、端末によって積んでいるメモリ量は違いますので、実機でのみメモリ警告が出ることは当然あります。